# Strange value for available physical memory

Tags: windows, winapi

I use a code library that contains a function to calculate the amount of memory avaliable.

For hosted PC's (hosted by Windows 2008 R2 x64) I sometimes see the free amount calculated in a funny way.

It gets reported as

> physical memory   : 1400/1400 MB (free/total)

Which cant really be true, since several applications are running. How can that happen?

My interest here is whether this phenomenon points to a memory problem. Sometimes my application runs out of memory when hosted on a VM with limited memory like 1400 MB. So when I see a bug report with the available meory wrongly reported as 1400 MB could it be that it really is zero?

Here is the code

```
function GetMemoryStatus : UnicodeString;
type
  TMemoryStatusEx = record
    dwLength                : dword;
    dwMemoryLoad            : dword;
    ullTotalPhys            : int64;
    ullAvailPhys            : int64;
    ullTotalPageFile        : int64;
    ullAvailPageFile        : int64;
    ullTotalVirtual         : int64;
    ullAvailVirtual         : int64;
    ullAvailExtendedVirtual : int64;
  end;
var gmse : function (var mse: TMemoryStatusEx) : bool; stdcall;
    ms   : TMemoryStatus;
    mse  : TMemoryStatusEx;
begin
  gmse := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(kernel32), 'GlobalMemoryStatusEx');
  if @gmse <> nil then begin
    mse.dwLength := sizeOf(mse);
    gmse(mse);
  end else begin
    ms.dwLength := sizeOf(ms);
    GlobalMemoryStatus(ms);
    mse.ullAvailPhys := ms.dwAvailPhys;
    mse.ullTotalPhys := ms.dwTotalPhys;
  end;
  result := IntToStrExW((mse.ullAvailPhys + $80000) div $100000) + '/' +
            IntToStrExW((mse.ullTotalPhys + $80000) div $100000) + ' MB (free/total)';
end;
```

Thanks!
Jacob

Comment: I have encountered a bug within a Delphi Code. A 32 bit process won't get correct values for total and free memory.

Comment: There were functions for it in MagWMI and OmniThreadsLib. I don;t think they should fail anyway. 1st uses WMI service and for 2nd that might be rather important info to get it wrong.  http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magwmi.asp  http://otl.17slon.com

Comment: Well we had the same problems with one of our companies applications, but I am no Delphi developer, I just wanted to tell, that there may be a bug in the code, that gets the values from the operatin system.

Comment: This is madExcept code. Why don't you ask on the madExcept forum? Anyway, do I take it from your question, that this only happens inside virtual machines?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach How could the values returned from a Windows API function be classed as a Delphi bug?

Comment: You're sure 'IntToStrExW' (whatever that is) is not playing a trick on you?

Comment: @Sertac It's madExcept. That function is to avoid taking a dependency on SysUtils. The values reported are those returned by OS.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach: That's not true. I just tested code very similar to that above from a Delphi 2007 app running on Win7 64-bit, and got the correct results.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes I did ask the author of madExcept and he thinks its probably a bug in the Win32 API. And yes I've only seen it in virtual machines. Sometimes the number looks ok, sometimes its like this, I havent spotted any pattern to this problem. Sorry if I've mistagged it with the Delphi tag.

Comment: @user I doubt that it's a bug. I expect it's just an oddity in the way the VM is implemented.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I edited the question to clarify the relevance. Also removed the Delphi tag since I don't think its related to Delphi..

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem. The only difference is some changes to the calculations you're doing in the `Result` line, because I don't have MadExcept on the system I'm on right now (will rectify that soon). Here's the code I used:

```
type
  TMemoryStatusEx = record
    dwLength                : dword;
    dwMemoryLoad            : dword;
    ullTotalPhys            : int64;
    ullAvailPhys            : int64;
    ullTotalPageFile        : int64;
    ullAvailPageFile        : int64;
    ullTotalVirtual         : int64;
    ullAvailVirtual         : int64;
    ullAvailExtendedVirtual : int64;
  end;

type
  TGlobalMemoryStatusEx = function (var mse: TMemoryStatusEx) : bool; stdcall;

function GetMemoryStatus : string;
var
  GlobalMemoryStatusEX: TGlobalMemoryStatusEx;
  MemStatEx  : TMemoryStatusEx;
begin
  GlobalMemoryStatusEx := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(kernel32),
                              'GlobalMemoryStatusEx');
  if @GlobalMemoryStatusEx <> nil then
  begin
    MemStatEx.dwLength := sizeOf(MemStatEx);
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(MemStatEx);
    Result := Format('%d / %d KB (free/total), ',
                [MemStatEx.ullAvailPhys div 1024,
                 MemStatEx.ullTotalPhys div 1024 ]);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := GetMemoryStatus;
end;
```

Here's the output of the app (with Task Manager's Physical Memory pane beneath it for comparison), running in a Windows XP Mode virtual machine on Windows 7. The VM was set up with 1GB of RAM, and has this test app, Task Manager, and a single Windows Explorer instance running. (The app was written in D2007 on Win 7 64-bit, and then copied/pasted into the VM and started by double-clicking in Explorer.)

[image: Test app with Task Man bkgrnd]

Comment: I can't quite see where you are going with this.

Comment: You are welcome and now I think it is time to clean up this mess of comments!  ;-)

Comment: @David, done. :-) I'm still trying to reproduce this, now that the poster has indicated it's not a MadExcept or Delphi issue, but I'm not able to do so in VirtualBox or VirtualPC with XP 32-bit or Win7 64.